# Who were the other two heroes with Superman in the newspaper article who left?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

In *Justice League*, we see a newspaper article showing three heroes who died (left to their home planets) but it was too fast that I missed catching the faces.

Who were the other two heroes who are dead?

Comment: Seems to be a reference to a [seemingly disproportionate number](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36447/did-a-disproportionate-number-of-celebrities-die-in-2016) of celebs dying in 2016

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There were three pictures

[image]

Left to Right:

### David Bowie / Superman / Prince

It's a tabloid paper headline which implies that a couple of *iconic* pop characters might have been aliens....like Superman.

Comment: Note: Prince died on the way back to his home planet.

Comment: "It's a tabloid paper headline which implies that a couple of _iconic_ pop characters might have been aliens....like Superman." The jury's out on Prince, but as for Bowie...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bowie#Ziggy_Stardust

Comment: Two other heroes indeed.

Comment: Also relevant for Bowie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Fell_to_Earth